# Package json exports subpath issue

Tags: npm, path, package, npm-package

I have an npm package called @hakit/core, this package has an exports property setup:

```
{
  "name": "@hakit/core",
  "type": "module",
  "bin": {
    "hakit-sync-types": "./dist/sync/cli.js"
  },
  "main": "dist/hakit-core.umd.js",
  "module": "dist/hakit-core.es.js",
  "types": "dist/types/index.d.cts",
  "exports": {
    ".": {
      "import": "./dist/hakit-core.es.js",
      "require": "./dist/hakit-core.umd.js",
      "types": "./dist/types/index.d.cts"
    },
    "./sync": {
      "import": "./dist/sync/index.cjs",
      "require": "./dist/sync/index.cjs",
      "types": "./dist/sync/index.d.cts"
    }
  },
  "files": [
    "dist",
    "package.json",
    "README.md",
    "LICENCE.md"
  ],
}
```

However i simply cannot access the sync files via a subpath, the bin script works fine, so i know the paths are correct

```
import { typeSync } from '@hakit/core/sync';
```

When i try to import this function from /sync typescript says `Cannot find module '@hakit/core/sync' or its corresponding type declarations.`

Here's a JSON dump of my file structure:

```
{
  "path": "dist",
  "name": "dist",
  "children": [
    {
      "path": "dist/hakit-core.es.js",
      "name": "hakit-core.es.js"
    },
    {
      "path": "dist/hakit-core.umd.js",
      "name": "hakit-core.umd.js"
    },
    {
      "path": "dist/sync",
      "name": "sync",
      "children": [
        {
          "path": "dist/sync/cli.js",
          "name": "cli.js"
        },
        {
          "path": "dist/sync/index.cjs",
          "name": "index.cjs"
        },
        {
          "path": "dist/sync/index.d.cts",
          "name": "index.d.cts"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "path": "dist/types",
      "name": "types",
      "children": [
        {
          "path": "dist/types/index.d.cts",
          "name": "index.d.cts"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Any help identifying what the issue is would be great!

Comment: types has to be first aparently, this was my issue